# Obtain a token from a POST request

Tags: c#, webrequest, rest

I'm trying to obtain a token from a POST request, but I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to read the response.  I'm also not really sure how to put the username and password in the body of the message.  I tried using `httpWReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUsername","myPassword")` but that wasn't working.

The documentation states:

[image: Documentation]

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                    "https://myportalURI.com/token");

string s = "user=myUserName,password=myPassword";
var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

var newStream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream();

newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

newStream.Close();
```

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` is very old. I recommend, you try looking at `HttpClient` instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0. That will of course require some new coding, but it will be worth it - and there's a lot of questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: Use `HttpClient`.

Comment: Secondly, it's expecting JSON. `"user=myUserName,password=myPassword";` is not JSON.

Comment: When you look for answers here include `[httpclient]` in the search.

Comment: mm, yeah, I see that.  I'm not used to putting a message in the body.  Usually I can just do something like `httpWReq.Headers.Add("user","pw");` but I guess in this case I can't do that.

Comment: To answer your original question, you would need to send the request (i.e. `httpWReq.GetResponse`) before there is a response to read. But yeah, your endpoint wants Json, and `HttpClient` is way more awesomer.